# Mongo DB Collection - Count values of an attribute

Tags: mongodb

I have a mongo db with companies with the following data structure:

```
{'Beschreibung': [],
 'Branche': ['Doctor'],
 'Homepage': 'http://www.doctorsdomain.de',
 'Mail': None,
 'Name': ['Companyname'],
 'Ort': 'Doctors City',
 'PLZ': '12345 ',
 'StrHausnummer': 'Doctors Street',
 'Telefonnummer': '1235345646',
 '_id': ObjectId('sadfsdfawdfawedfbad5f'),
 'domain': 'doctorsdomain',
 'doctors': [{'Salutation': 'Dear Madame', 'Name': 'Maximiliane Mustermann'},
                    {'Salutation': 'Dear Mister', 'Name': 'Bernd Beispiel'}],
'other information'
```

I don't find the query to count how many names (doctors) I have in my database.

I tried something like

```
collection.find({"doctors":{"$exists":1}}).count()
```

but than I only get the number of the companies where doctors exists.

Need help please!

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [count total number of elements inside an array in document - MongoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34268176/count-total-number-of-elements-inside-an-array-in-document-mongodb)

Comment: Refer linked duplicate. Include `{"$match":{"doctors":{"$exists":1}}}` to only look for documents where doctors array is present.